# user level issue with redirecting

Tags: php

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [checklogin condition issue in php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11988317/checklogin-condition-issue-in-php)

i have this quick question please,

i have this piece of code which isn't working properly, something about the syntax.. could you please help me with it?

i know it may sound stupid enough but i'm trying to understand!

Thanks!

```
<?php 
session_start();
require_once('db.php'); 
include('functions.php'); 
if (checkLogin('1 2')) {
    echo "hello ".$_SESSION['user_id']." You are now logged in."; 
} else if (checkLogin('3'))  {
echo "hey tst";
} else {}

?>


function checkLogin($levels)
    {
        if(!$_SESSION['logged_in'])
        {
            $access = FALSE;
        }
        else {
            $kt = split(' ', $levels);

            $query = mysql_query('SELECT Level_access FROM users WHERE ID = "'.mysql_real_escape_string($_SESSION['user_id']).'"');
            $row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query);

            $access = FALSE;

            while(list($key,$val)=each($kt))
            {
                if($val==$row['Level_access'])
                {//if the user level matches one of the allowed levels
                    $access = TRUE;
                }
            }
        }
        if($access==FALSE)
        {
            header("Location: login.php");
        }
        else {
        //do nothing: continue
        }

    }

CREATE TABLE `users` (
  `ID` int(11) NOT NULL auto_increment,
  `Username` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `Password` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `Temp_pass` varchar(55) default NULL,
  `Temp_pass_active` tinyint(1) NOT NULL default '0',
  `Email` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `Active` int(11) NOT NULL default '0',
  `Level_access` int(11) NOT NULL default '2',
  `Random_key` varchar(32) default NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY  (`ID`),
  UNIQUE KEY `Username` (`Username`),
  UNIQUE KEY `Email` (`Email`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=2 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=2 ;
```

Comment: Hey darren thanks... well, there is an error with the way i wrote it because it gives me red lines in dreamweaver.. but i don't know why...

Comment: If you run your code, it will generate an error. Forget about Dreamweaver's error detection, because it's faulty at best. Once you get a grasp of what the red lines MIGHT mean by running the code, you won't need to ask questions like this in the future.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well you could simplify your checkLogin() function

```
function checkLogin($levels)
{

    $access = false;

    if (!isset($_SESSION['logged_in']) || !$_SESSION['logged_in']) 
        return false;

  //use mysqli instead mysql
$con = new mysqli("localhost", "username", "password", "database");

$query = $con->query('SELECT Level_access FROM users WHERE ID = "'.$con->real_escape_string($_SESSION['user_id']).'"');
$row = $query->fetch_assoc();

$con->close();

    if (in_array($row['Level_access'], explode(" ", $levels))) $access = true;

    return $access;

}
```

This function should return true or false!

After that your code could look like this

```
session_start();
require_once('db.php'); 
include('functions.php'); 
if (checkLogin('1 2')) {
    echo "hello ".$_SESSION['user_id']." You are now logged in."; 
} else if (checkLogin('3'))  {
    echo "hey tst";
} else {
    header("Location: login.php");
}
```

Hope this helps you.

Comment: hey, thanks for trying... i don't know, but when i use this code it just redirects me to login.php...

Comment: well you could show you database structure for users so I could test it

Comment: Yes thanks.. this would be the database, i'll update the question now

Comment: @Al12: I updated my answer, it should be working for you as I tested it on my computer!

Comment: Worked like a charm :)
Many Many Many thank you to you :)
Thanks...

Answer (score 0):

Your [`if` statements](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.if.php) need parenthesis around them:

```
if( checkLogin('1 2')) {
  ^                  ^
```

Comment: Hy, thanks for the reply.. i did that, but when i do it it seems like it doesn't work anymore..

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<?php 
session_start();
require_once('db.php'); 
include('functions.php'); 
if (checkLogin('1 2')) {
    echo "hello ".$_SESSION['user_id']." You are now logged in."; 
} else if (checkLogin('3'))  {
echo "hey tst";
} else {}

?>
```

Comment: hey thanks, the problem is that when i put the function in brackets it stops excecuting the login script..

Comment: there is the correct one

Comment: Hey i'm sorry, i meant i updated the question with the checklogin..but it still doesn't work..

Answer (score 0):

Run the code in your browser. You'll get an error message. Use that error message to figure out what's wrong. Repeat until you get no error messages, and the program runs as designed.

That's how we debug things in the real world.

Comment: Hello Matt, i've already done that and if i knew how to solve it i wouldn't be asking here i guess... i realize it must be something simple, i really realize it, but due to me being a non expert i don't have much "imagination" to how to solve it! i know i have to read and study lot more, i know, but i'm doing it! meanwhile i'm stucked with this problem!

Comment: Then *post the error message you're getting*. And don't tell me there's the red line under your code. That's not an error message.

Comment: Well, if i keep the code as i've posted here... in the question, i don't get any error, but after inserting username and password it still stays in login.php, i guess there might be something with the checkLogin function!